# .closest() is not working?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show').click(function(e){
        $(this).closest('.b').css('display','block');
        e.preventDefault;
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.b{ display:none; }
</style>

<div class="a"><a href="#" class="show">show content 1</a></div>
<div class="b">content 1</div>

<div class="a"><a href="#" class="show">show content 2</a></div>
<div class="b">content 2</div>

<div class="a"><a href="#" class="show">show content 3</a></div>
<div class="b">content 3</div>
```

fiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/dus4a/3/

so basically I have 3 content to show if I press the link 
but the closest wont run, can u guys tell me what is wrong ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: it wont work because `.b` isn't the parent of `.show`. `e.preventDefault()` you forgot `()`.

Comment: jsfiddle is empty!!!!

Comment: ah sorry updated the jsfiddle link

Comment: @Omar so closest is for parent ?

Comment: Yes John, http://api.jquery.com/closest/ read the differences between it and `parents()`.

Comment: oh I just knew that closest is for parent only
the code that I showed here are for example, because in my real code I am confused why the closest is not working....
well that is why is not working
Thanks a lot Omar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$('.show').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next('.b').css('display', 'block');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dus4a/1/

Comment: my code is only an example, my real code is more than this I just wonder why closest is not working....
but I already get the answer from Omar
thanks I will accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(this).parent().next().css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method is looking for the first element that matches the selector by looking up *through its ancestors in the DOM tree*. That means that it will only work if you're looking for a parent. It is interesting to note that the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method is very similar to the [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method, in that they both search through the parents, but the later will return more than one element if more that one matches your selector.

In your case, you would look for sibling, not parents. The simplest to get the next sibling is to use the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method. Note that you can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) with or without a selector. If used without a selector, it will return the immediately following sibling, while if you provide a selector it will return the first sibling matching your selector.

Taking your HTML code as-is, here is how you would reach the `.b` element that is next to each `.a` element (which is the parent of your link):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show').click(function(e){
        $(this).parent()   // Get the ".a" first
               .next('.b') // Get the next element after ".a" and that matches ".b" (could also be used without selector)
               .css('display','block');
        e.preventDefault;
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.b{ display:none; }
</style>

<div class="a"><a href="#" class="show">show content 1</a></div>
<div class="b">content 1</div>

<div class="a"><a href="#" class="show">show content 2</a></div>
<div class="b">content 2</div>

<div class="a"><a href="#" class="show">show content 3</a></div>
<div class="b">content 3</div>
```

Here you can see this exact code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/YVNDy/6/

Cheers!